# Spring-Security OAuth2 StackOverflowError using Java config

Tags: java, xml, spring, oauth, spring-security

I have a working Spring-Security OAuth2 configuration using XML, which I am trying to convert to a Java-based config. This is a simple password grant scenario, with both the authorization and resource servers in the same app. The XML configuration works fine. However, when accessing the /oauth/token endpoint to request a token, the Java-based configuration gives a StackOverflowError, looping on

```
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:446)    
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192).
```

What gives?

Java config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyAppSpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("supersecret")
                .roles("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2AuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("myclient")
                    .secret("password123")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("ROLE_APP")
                    .scopes("myapp")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60); // 1 hour
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class OAuth2ResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/services/**").and()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/services/**").authenticated();
        }
    }
}
```

XML config (working):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <sec:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
        <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

        <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>

        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>

        <sec:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </sec:http>

    <sec:http pattern="/services/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

        <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>

        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>

        <sec:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </sec:http>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="myapp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="myapp/client"/>
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="bcryptPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:user-service>
                <sec:user name="admin" password="supersecret" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </sec:user-service>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"/>

    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="3600"/>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:refresh-token/>
        <oauth:password/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="myapp" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth:client client-id="myapp" secret="password123" authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token" scope="myapp" authorities="ROLE_APP"/>
    </oauth:client-details-service>
</beans>
```

I know a lot of the stuff specified in the XML is defaulted through @EnableAuthorizationServer and @EnableResourceServer, but apparently I'm still missing something. I've gone back and forth over the sample apps and unit tests. But there always seems to additionally be more Spring Boot related magic going on in those configs.

This is with Spring 4.2.3, Spring Security 4.0.3, and Spring Security OAuth 2.0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expose the AuthenticationManager instance as a bean, you need to override `public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()` rather than `protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager()`.

See JavaDoc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#authenticationManagerBean--

Comment: Bitten by the simplest of mistakes, overriding the method that has the right name rather than the real one buried in the Javadocs. Thanks Christophe.